# How to convert date with time along with UTC (18/Sep/2012:09:57:41 -0500) to timestamp in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to convert 18/Sep/2012:09:57:41 -0500 to timestamp in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date' 

date = Date.parse("18/Sep/2012:09:57:41 -0500")
date.to_time.to_i # => 1568782800
```

Answer (score 0):

It's safest to use the class method [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and then convert the resulting `DateTime` object to a `Time` object with [DateTime#to_time](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_time).

The components of the format string used by `DateTime#strptime` are given in the doc for [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime).

```
str = "18/Sep/2012:09:57:41 -0500"
```

```
require 'time'

fmt = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z"
DateTime.strptime(str, fmt).to_time
  #=> 2012-09-18 09:57:41 -0500
```

```
Date.parse "Date::parse may work in unexpected ways so I tend to avoid using it."
  #=> #<Date: 2019-05-01 ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```